# Creating a loop using non-unique ID-numbers in R instead of using rownumbers for the iteration

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

Really struggled to come up with a proper title but hopefully, this will explain what my problem is:

Let's say I have a dataset (or vector) where one column is a numerical Frame_ID column but they are not unique IDs. For example Frame_ID = c( 2 , 2  ,2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 7 , 7 , 8 , 8 , 8  , 9 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 11 etc.) and this continues until Frame_ID=159753, without any specific pattern or rule that would explain how many times a Frame_ID is repeated. Now I would like to add for every 30 Frame_IDs a corresponding timestamp (1 second per 30 Frame_IDs) in a new column, so it eventually looks like this:

| Frame_ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 14:30:19 |
| 2 | 14:30:19 |
| 2 | 14:30:19 |
| 3 | 14:30:19 |
| ... | .... |
| 30 | 14:30:19 |
| 31 | 14:30:20 |
| 31 | 14:30:20 |

I created this function but besides not really working conceptually I believe, it also uses the row numbers and not the actual Frame_ID values for i. How can I work it out so that it treats the actual Frame_ID values for the iterations and i and not the rownumbers? Hope that makes sense.

Thanks already in advance, any hint is highly appreciated.

```
real_time <- c()
start = hms('14:30:19')
for (i in 0:159753) {
  start <- data$Frame_ID[i:i+30]
  real_time[i] <- start
  i = i + 30
  start = start + 1
  print(real_time)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Frame_ID = c(2,2,2,3,30,31,31,39,59,60,69))

df$grp <- floor(df$Frame_ID/30)

df$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct("2000/01/01 14:30:19") + df$grp
df
#>    Frame_ID grp           Timestamp
#> 1         2   0 2000-01-01 14:30:19
#> 2         2   0 2000-01-01 14:30:19
#> 3         2   0 2000-01-01 14:30:19
#> 4         3   0 2000-01-01 14:30:19
#> 5        30   1 2000-01-01 14:30:20
#> 6        31   1 2000-01-01 14:30:20
#> 7        31   1 2000-01-01 14:30:20
#> 8        39   1 2000-01-01 14:30:20
#> 9        59   1 2000-01-01 14:30:20
#> 10       60   2 2000-01-01 14:30:21
#> 11       69   2 2000-01-01 14:30:21

format(df$Timestamp, format = "%H:%M:%S")
#>  [1] "14:30:19" "14:30:19" "14:30:19" "14:30:19" "14:30:20" "14:30:20"
#>  [7] "14:30:20" "14:30:20" "14:30:21" "14:30:21" "14:30:21"
Created on 2021-10-13 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using loops sounds inefficient here. Would this work for you?

```
data %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = as.character(hms('14:30:19') + floor(Frame_ID/30)))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying :) It looks good but how would it automatically continue then with 14:30:20 and so forth? I tried it though, it comes up with this error when I try it - 'Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Timestamp`. i `Timestamp = hms("14:30:19") + floor(Frame_ID/30)`. x Internal error in `df_slice()`: Columns must match the data frame size.' ...

Comment: adding `as.character()` should solve that. I edited my answer to match. As for your question: It checks for the entire column "at once" so you don't need to worry about looping. If `Frame_ID` is between 30 and 59 `floor(Frame_ID/30)` will be 1, therefore for all rows where `Frame_ID` is between 30 and 59 the timestamp will be `Timestamp` + 1.  If `Frame_ID` is between 150 and 179 `floor(Frame_ID/30)` will be 5, therefore for all rows where `Frame_ID` is between 150 and 179 the timestamp will be `Timestamp` + 5. etc